# Library for converting PPTX presentations to HTML

Tags: .net, html, powerpoint

I'm looking for a .NET-library which allows me to convert PPTX-presentations (MS PowerPoint) to HTML. It should support animations and keep fidelity of original presentations.
Which ones would you recommend?

My goal is to stream pptx-presentations to several participants as html. It's kind of conferencing app like MS Lync in PP sharing mode.

p.s. I'm aware of Aspose. It can export ppt to SVG but not pptx.

Comment: If you have powerpoint itself install on the machine where the app is to be running, you can use COM to invoke PP and save your PPTX as PPT - and then use Aspose.

Comment: @Aleks G, no, I'd like a user to upload his presentation to server and then it'd delivered to other users as HTML in web-app (with no any plugin)

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do.  Naturally, the presentation is to be uploaded - but what about the actual PowerPoint application?  If you can install it on the server, then you can communicate with it from .NET to run a conversion.

Comment: Yeah, I've understood your point now: convert pptx into ppt and then use Aspose to convert to html. it's an idea...

Comment: But, anyway Aspose doesn't support animations (while exporting to SVG)

Comment: Hm... good point. In fact, SVG in itself does not support animation, so you'd need to use ECMAScript or similar to do the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the author has already found a solution, but perhaps my answer will be useful for anyone else with a similar issue. One can use iSpring Platform (http://www.ispringsolutions.com/ispring-platform) to deal with this task. This is a COM SDK that allows programs using .NET to convert PowerPoint presentations into HTML5 and Flash. It also supports all the animations, effects, and all the ppt capabilities. All the published presentations can be managed by Javascript, so it’s possible to use them in online conferencing apps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer and it still doesnt answer all because of the lacking animation support but Aspose does support PPTX to HTML and SVG.

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/slidesnet/Converting+PPTX+to+HTML

```
PresentationEx pres = new PresentationEx(docStream);
string css = "html,body{padding:0;margin:0;}";
css += ".slide{border:1px solid #ddd;}";

SlideImageFormat slideImageFormat = SlideImageFormat.Svg(new SVGOptions());
HtmlFormatter htmlFormatter = HtmlFormatter.CreateDocumentFormatter(css, false);
HtmlOptions opts = new HtmlOptions {
  SlideImageFormat = slideImageFormat,
  HtmlFormatter = htmlFormatter
};

pres.Save(Response.OutputStream, SaveFormat.Html, opts);
```

Additionally, you could add JavaScript to load animations afterwards based on id or some custom engine.